# In active directory, what is mailNickname used for?

Tags: .net, active-directory, adsi

In active directory, should mailNickname always equal samaccountname? Or, should it always be equal to the mail property (minus the "@domain")?

My reason for asking is that we have recently changed everyone's primary email address to the first.last form and we set the mail property to the same. But, do we also need to modify the mailNickname property?

Thanks

Comment: Not-programming-related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mailNickName is an email alias.
If you are using Exchange then you would need to change the mail address policy which would update the mail attribute. If you use the policy you can also specify additional formats or domains for each user.

Comment: So it's another spot for an alias as opposed to the proxyAddresses property?

Comment: I think that mailnickname could be used as an alternative in name resolution against the internal address book, proxyaddresses are used for incoming email where you can have additional formats and additional domains per user. I have not verified this.

Answer (score 2):

No, it does *not* have to be the same as sAMAccountName. It just so happens that it usually is the same.