# Create a Security group in Azure and MailNickname

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm creating a New Security group in azure powershell.
The wizard asks me for a DisplayName and...for a MailNickname and I can't understand why.
[image: powershell]

Thanks

Comment: Because it's a **required** [parameter](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/main/src/Resources/Resources/help/New-AzADGroup.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

`DisplayName` and `MailNickname` both are required parameters.

**New-AzADGroup**

```
New-AzADGroup -DisplayName <String> -MailNickname <String> [-Description <String>]
 [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]
```

**DisplayName**

The display name for the group.

```
Type: System.String
Parameter Sets: (All)
Aliases:

Required: True
Position: Named
Default value: None
Accept pipeline input: True (ByPropertyName)
Accept wildcard characters: False
```

**MailNickname**

The mail nickname for the group. Cannot contain the @ sign.

```
Type: System.String
Parameter Sets: (All)
Aliases:

Required: True
Position: Named
Default value: None
Accept pipeline input: True (ByPropertyName)
Accept wildcard characters: False
```

You can refer to [New-AzADGroup](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/main/src/Resources/Resources/help/New-AzADGroup.md)

Comment: Hi DeepDave-MT, Thank you for reply. My Question is why is necessary/mandatory mail nickname for a security group. Thank you

Comment: You can refer to [In active directory, what is mailNickname used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504868/in-active-directory-what-is-mailnickname-used-for)